# How to make 6 Monitors + VR work of one computer?

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop, multiple-monitors

I have a EVGA RTX 3080 TI graphics card, 32 GB RAM and i9-10900 CPU. I'm wondering if I can make a setup of 6 monitors and a VR headset work. I typically use just one monitor for video games and the rest would be for browsing or watching a youtube video and such.

The graphics card only has 4 inputs so I know I can setup 4 monitors in such a way, however I've been reading about these USB to HDMI hubs and I'm wondering if my system can support the setup that I want. I don't want to risk frying my computer (spent a lot of time and money building it) and I also don't want to waste money buying extra monitors if I can't use them.

As such, if there is a setup where what I want is possible, I'd appreciate your advice and maybe an amazon link or two of the products I need to purchase in order to make this happen. Please let me know of any downfalls you are aware if I try and do this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: As a rule of thumb... 1 GPU, 3 screens max, no matter how good it is. VR headset will need its own GPU, so you'll probably need three in all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have integrated graphics (probably yes), you can connect a few monitors to that. USB to HDMI only works with thunderbolt or USB-C+DP, which I don't know if you have. You cannot fry your pc with incompatible adapters, it will just not work and you will have a few black screens.

Answer (score 1):

The `EVGA RTX 3080 TI graphics card` has 3 full size DP outputs and 1 full size HDMI output, according to https://www.evga.com/products/product.aspx?pn=12G-P5-3967-KR

you want a `screen splitter` or `monitor splitter` for either DP or HDMI.  And plan accordingly for what's going to hook up to what.  Assuming 6 monitors that are all connected via DP, and your VR headset as HDMI, then the 1 x HDMI satisfies the VR connection.  And then if you ran a 1:2 DP splitter off each of the 3 graphics card DP ports that would give you 6 monitors.  But be aware of the splitter if it requires USB power.  Splitting a display output signal at 1920x1080 or 3840x2160 for example, to multiple monitors each having the same resolution and showing all the same signal is somewhat trivial.  For HDMI you have to watch out for the HDCP protection which can be problematic; I don't know if that is still the case for DisplayPort.  And be sure to look at the specs that the splitter supports full resolution across everything it splits the original signal to.

fyi : https://www.tripplite.com/products/multi-stream-transport-mst-hub-technology

But if by 6 monitors you want your single 3840x2160 display extended across 6 monitors having a total resolution size of 23040x12960 then that's something entirely different.

Comment: Can you give me a link on amazon to a 1:2 DP splitter so I can take a look and see what you mean exactly?

Comment: https://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?id=pcat17071&st=display+port+splitter

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-2-Port-DisplayPort-MST-Hub/dp/B00XXPYGPO

Comment: just type `displayport splitter` in the search in amazon... check this one: https://www.amazon.com/HEZOOMS-DisplayPort-Splitter-8K-Adapter/dp/B09B9KDZRQ/ref=sr_1_8?crid=JFQST06PW1PD&keywords=Displayport+splitter&qid=1646061064&s=electronics&sprefix=displayport+splitter%2Celectronics%2C84&sr=1-8

Comment: Thank you, just one last question if you don't mind. Will windows detect 2 separate monitors if I use a splitter like this? For example if I go to display settings, will I be able to adjust the position of the monitors. Monitor 1 on the left and Monitor 2 on the right... etc...?

Comment: i don't think so, not with a splitter.  Windows or any OS will only see those physical DP ports off the graphics card and can only work with those.  If you split the output from one of those to many, Windows I don't think will recognize that split.  But read up on the splitter manufacturer info and DisplayPort specfifications to find out.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to do something like this then? https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07WYD88M6 in addition to use the 4 ports in the graphic card? Put lets say 3 monitors on the hub that connects via usb and then 3 monitors via dp ports of graphic card and VR of HDMI.

Comment: no I don't think so.  That QGeeM your linking to is a *Docking Station* and does not offer any video splitting which is what you initially stated you needed... your one graphics card has 3 DP outputs and 1 HDMI output but you need to drive 6 monitors + a VR *headset*.  If the VR runs off the 1 HDMI, then your stuck with making 3 DP run 6 monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add a second video card.

4 devices on your main card
3 devices on your 2nd card (2+VR =3)

Your probably going to want the extra GPU anyway to get the most FPS and/or 4k or etc you want.